# Openstack Error Unable to establish connection to keystone endpoint

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, ubuntu-16.04, openstack

I am trying to perform Openstack installation on Ubuntu Server 16.04

I am using following scenario.

> Host Machine : Windows 7 ( IP : 192.168.1.15) installed VMWare
> application in it.
>
> Guest Machine : Ubuntu Server 16.04 (IP : provided by VMWare DHCP
> 192.168.30.178)
>
> Network Adapter : NAT ( VMNet8)

successfully installed openstack on it.

later when I want to access **openstack dashboard** from my host machine `http://192.168.30.178/dashboard` , I changed network adapter of my **virtual machine to bridged** , so it changes my virtual machine IP address to
( 192.168.1.52). so now , when i try to connect `http://192.168.1.52/dashboard` from my host machine, it open user authetication screen . I entered

> username as **admin** and
>
> password as **mypassword**(set by me in local.conf file)

But it **failed with error Unable to establish connection to keystone endpoint.** I checked error log file `/var/log/apache2/horizon_error.log` , it gives following error

```
ERROR openstack_auth.plugin.base Unable to establish connection to http://192.168.30.178/identity/v3/auth/tokens : HttpConnectionPool( Host='192.168.30.178' ,port='80')
```

this means that horizon using my old IP address (192.168.30.178).
So please help to change my old IP address with new IP address.How to update that.my new IP address is 192.168.1.52 . I changed my local.conf file with this new IP.
please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Openstack installation or re-install it with the new IP
Otherwise go into every component configuration file and change the IP address in it
for keystone and all other components

change any occurrence of 192.168.30.178 to 192.168.1.53 in all these files:

c:\<openstack configuration directory>\

keystone\keystone.conf

nova\nova.conf

cinder\cinder.conf

glance\glance.conf

neutron\neutron.conf

swift\swift.conf

gnocchi\gnocchi.conf

aodh\aodh.conf

ceilometer\ceilometer.conf

and restart the machine